# Specify views location just for controller?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I do not want to add view locations to the Global, but just need it for one controller. How do I specify a different view location from within the controller? A configuration in the controller constructor would be nice, but even if there is a way to do it in the actions: return View(??)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> A configuration in the controller constructor would be nice,

Yes you can inject the configuration item in constructor of a controller and yes that as the string path of the view

```
public class ExampleController : Controller
{
  private string ViewPath;
  public ExampleController(string viewPath)
  {
     ViewPath = viewPath;
  }

  public ActionResult Index(ExampleModel exampleModel)
  {
     return View(ViewPath);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could always specify the location of the view explicitly:

```
return View("~/Views/SomeSpecialLocation/Foo.cshtml", someModel);
```

Comment: does `cshtml` extension to be mentioned ?